# Maven local repository and compilation

Tags: maven, compilation

Currently I am trying configure maven to a local repository for ex `c:/maven-repo/repository`. For this I have changed the `<localRepository>` value in `M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` and pointed it to the above path.

When I execute any `mvn` command through command prompt, all required maven dependencies are geting downloaded to the given local repo path.

However, when I use `mvn -e clean install` for one of project, the maven is able to download the required dependencies to the local repository path, but the compilation fails.

When I put the `settings.xml` under `${user.home}/.m2` location the `mvn clean install` executes successfully.

Please note: the dependencies present under `${user.home}/.m2/repository` and under local repository path are same.

Is there any setting, that need to be done in maven, so that maven can use the dependencies present under local repository path instead of `${user.home}/.m2/repository` path.

My Parent `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycomp.test</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectArtifact</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Acrts</name>
<description>Parent Project</description>
<properties>
    <!-- tests librairies version -->
    <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>

    <!-- tools version -->
    <maven.version>2.0</maven.version>
    <java.source.version>1.7</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.7</java.target.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!--        <finalName>should_not_be_used</finalName>-->
    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>../Acrts/ACS_assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    <!--<descriptor>../Pub/ACS_assembly.xml</descriptor>--></descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    --></plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And my main projects `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <artifactId>ProjectArtifact</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.test</groupId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <web.inf.lib>WEB-INF/lib</web.inf.lib>
</properties>

<!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycomp.test</groupId>
<artifactId>MainProjectServer</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>${project.release.version}</version>
<name>AcrtsGwtServer</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.full</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
      <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acn.acs.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>SemiOnlineAcrtsService</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>target/www/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
                <runTarget>server.html</runTarget>
                <!-- Location of the develop-mode web application structure (gwt:run). -->
                <hostedWebapp>target/www</hostedWebapp>
                <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                <soyc>true</soyc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/www</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/www/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Delete gwt generated stuff -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/acrtsgwtserver</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>tomcat</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>www-test</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>.gwt-tmp</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Requesting you to help me, so that I can use the local repository instead of `${user.home}/.m2/repository`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the answer help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.xml is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:

1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,
                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
                 installation). It's normally provided in
                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.

Priority is given to the User Level settings.xml.

Use just one settings.xml. And change the value of the element `<localRepository>` to the desired location. I think that should do the job.